# Spring Boot prevent the swagger documentation from being access outside by adding sort of authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am adding swagger to my rest api, and it is public access and I want to add some kind of authentication so only the developer who will use it can know the Apis without being exposed.

Comment: Just include swagger url into your security no?

Comment: * and it is public access* *so only the developer who will use it c* its either public or developers only...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add basic authentication for the swagger URL so it isn't access without username and password through spring security class.

but while you are in development it doesn't matter to be authenticated but once you moved to production you can disable the swagger on your project.